# Easy: pass datatable to class

Tags: c#, class

Easy and quick question, I am ashamed to admit it, but I have forgotten how can you pass a datatable to a different class in C#.

let's say I want to pass my datatable TABLE from my main class to a different public class.

I feel so stupid asking this XD

Comment: don't be ashamed....search on google you can find it eaisly i think

Comment: I tried to google, but it seems the easiest questions ar the ones it's most dificult to find answers for. And yes , I tried to create a class for my datatable {get; set} and all of that.

Comment: Pass it along in the constructor of your public class?

Comment: Ok I get the idea of a constructor but I get completely lost when I need to create one for datatable that is related to another datatable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

by constructor :

```
class c1
{
   DataTable t1;
   public void callC2()
   {
       C2 c2=new C2(t1);
   }   
}

class c2
{
   DataTable t1;
   public C2(DataTable tbl)
   {
       t1=tbl;
   }
}
```

in method calling :

```
class c1
{
   DataTable t1;
   public void callC2()
   {
       C2 c2=new C2();
       c2.TargetMethod(t1);
   }   
}

class c2
{
   public void TargetMethod(DataTable tbl)
   {       
      for(int i=0;i<tbl.Rows.Count;i++)
      // Do your works with tbl

   }
}
```

Comment: wow! thanks a lot. Knew it shouldn't be hard, but couldn't figure it out. It's been years since I actually programmed something.